# How to tune the SM utilization (across the entire GPU) of a CUDA kernel?

Tags: c++, performance, cuda, gpu

I want to try experiments with CUDA MPS (Multi-Process Service). I want to launch many CUDA kernels on the GPU simultaneously (concurrently), such that each kernel without concurrent execution with the other kernels has almost the same end-to-end running time.

For example, I have a kernel, `KernA.` And I would like to launch many instances of this kernel `KernA` on the GPU simultaneously. So, I want to manually control (even hard-coding it into the `.cu` program is fine) the SM utilization of each instance. If I launch two kernel instances of `KernA` simultaneously, I want each instance alone to have an SM utilization of `50%`. [The input size does not matter to me. All I want is a kernel launch, where I can tune the SM utilization of each of them]. So that when two of them are run simultaneously on the GPU using CUDA MPS, `50%` of each would roughly make up `100%` of the GPU, and hence, time to run each instance alone would take the same as running those `2` kernels.

Similarly, if I want to launch `3` kernels simultaneously, I want each instance to have an SM utilization of around `33%` so that 3 of these kernels would make up a total of `100%` of the GPU.

Also, if I want to launch `4` kernels simultaneously, I want each instance to have an SM utilization of around `25%` so that 4 of these kernels would make up a total of `100%`.

...

Going by this line, if I want to launch `n` kernels simultaneously, I want each instance to have an SM utilization of around `(100/n) %` such that `n` of these kernels would make up a total of `100%`.

---

The first approach which I tried to take:

I tried using the CUDA runtime API : [cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OCCUPANCY.html#group__CUDART__OCCUPANCY_1ge99bee88c427b3f8ffa8ec3e43fd877d). I tried out the program example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28044011/7571421).

But, the problem I get in this above approach is as follows ( I am using `RTX2080` GPU):

- I tried to take the block size as input here. For block size = 32, I am getting `50%` utilization per SM.
- I half the block size like `16, 8, 4, 2, 1`... The utilization per SM halves as well, i.e., `25, 12.5, ...`
- Warp size of the GPU that I am using is `32`. If any, I use block size < warp size; as far as I know, the GPU system shall pad dummy threads to make up a total of 32  threads for a warp so that these total of `32` threads can work in a lock-step manner. Due to this padding, I guess I cannot launch more than two kernels concurrently (say with block size = 16 and 4 concurrent kernels) and expect them to get nicely packed in the GPU, as the example I mentioned above.
- The other parameter which I can twig is the number of blocks. The API mentioned above sets the maximum active block per SM. So, if for a kernel, the API designates the `numBlocks` variable to say `16` and reports `Occupancy: 50%`, we cannot just set `numBlocks=8` and launch the kernel (i.e., `kernA<<<8, 32>>>()`) and expect `25%` utilization of the entire GPU because my RTX2080 has 46 streaming multiprocessors (SMs). Why? Since the API adjusts `numBlocks` for a single SM, the expected GPU utilization over all the SMs shall be `25/46 %.`

---

The second approach which I tried to take is, keeping `blockSize` fixed; I am changing the value of `n` and hence causing `numBlocks = n/ blockSize` to adjust manually by hit-and-trial and checking the instantaneous change in the GPU utilization through the `nvidia-smi` command. But I do not find this approach quite concrete. And for smaller kernels, the execution time is so small that the kernel finishes execution without showing any change in the GPU % utilization in the `watch -n 0.1 nvidia-smi` command.

---

I am using this simple kernel for testing:

```cuda
__global__ void MyKernel(float* a, float* b, float* c, int n)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (idx < n)
    {
        c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];
    }
}
```

---

Also, any specific way to confirm that my kernel, while executing, is making use of `x%` of the GPU apart from using `watch -n 0.1 nvidia-smi` command? Any profiling tool, for example, `ncu`, and how to check that?

Comment: It might be worth looking into GPU virtualisation as a way to achieve what you want, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Every algorithm & every hardware combination would have a different balance for every specific usage-percentage. You can write a benchmarking tool that gradually increments number of CUDA threads to launch until it reaches 100% usage (or until the total run-time of all work starts increasing exactly linearly). Then just pick closest integer-multiple of number of threads per block to separate the work into N clients with equal percentage.

Though less efficiently, you can do this too:

- launch all clients kernels
- measure (overlapped) time taken
- equalize times by subtracting/adding (CUDA) threads to clients iteratively on each new kernel launch
- repeat until timings are equalized